# MS Excel Formula: Find Position/Location of a Word in a String

Tags: excel, string, search, excel-formula, position

Using a MS Excel Formula (Not VBA), I would like to find the actual position/location of a specific word found within a String.  If this is possible, I'd like to use a "Search and/or Replace" versus "Find or Substitute" function, as the text string is not an absolute by letter casing.

Cell A1 (Text String):  "The dog ran behind the house and then jumped the fence."
Cell B1: (Target Keyword):  Ran
Cell C1 (Position of Word): 3

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following would give you the word-index of the first word that **contains** your substring:

```
=SEARCH(B1,A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH(B1,A1))," ",""))+1
```

If you have access to `FILTERXML` you can retrieve it by throwing in some `MATCH` and this would return the word-index of an **exact** match:

```
=MATCH(B1,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),0)
```

**Note:** The second formula needs to be entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

As per @BigBen, you might run into troubled water if your string holds special characters like comma and the likes. In that case, you might want to throw in more nested `SUBSTITUTE` formulas to take care of that scenario.

---

If you need multiple matches, and you want it concatenated into a single cell, you'll need access to the `TEXTJOIN` function. To get all word-indexes of words that **contain** your substring:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))),ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))),""))
```

To get all **exact** matches that hold your lookup value:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")=B1,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))),""))
```

**Note:** Both formulas needs to be entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Yeah. This problem is non-trivial.

Comment: @BigBen, not quite =)

Comment: Well what if the sentence was `"The dog ran, then sped, behind the house and then jumped the fence."`?

Comment: HA touché! @BigBen, that would require a few more `SUBSTITUTES` to be thrown in =)

Comment: ^^^ Exactly ^^^. Which is why a simple example blows up when OP tries to apply it to the actual data at hand. You can imagine the follow-up questions :-)

Comment: Thanks JvdV... and also BigBen... Are you able to provide me with an alternate solution that will overcome this obstacle, that includes if using a SUBSTITUTE formula to yield the best possible results.  I did experience the issue mentioned as per BigBen, when the word/text within the string itself has a character conjoined to the target keyword

Comment: @miaka3, you can only try to limit the odds of unwanted answer by including more nested `SUBSTITUTE` functions to get rid of identified special characters like comma and dot. Unfortunately it's indeed non-trivial.

Comment: Thanks JvdV... I truly appreciate your assistance and help.  I've gotten grey hair attempting to figure this one out... Thanks Agagin

Comment: JvdV... Is there a way if possible to show the position of a keyword that is found multiple times within a cell/string.  i.e., "The dog ran behind the house, then ran across the street".  Ran = Target Keyword.  Ran = 3 and Ran =8 and so forth if multiple keywords are identified within the string.

Comment: @miaka3, it's possible if you have got the TEXTJOIN function available.

Comment: Thanks JvdV, I do have TEXTJOIN functionality will test shortly and let you know... And as always thank you very much for your assistance.